# Define a pattern for texts fonts size in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Is there a way to define the text fonts size in a separated file? In android, we can use a xml file Called dimens to reuse fonts size and other layout patterns for our app. Is there a similar thing in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to just create a class for it and put them in there as constants. There's no similar thing to the dimens.xml file in iOS that I know of.